# How to enable SSL connection for a GCP VM instance (Mautic)

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, mautic

I have a Mautic deployment on GCP. I used Bitnami installation for the deployment. I'm having issues with integrating apps / receiving tag messages because the default Bitnami installation only supports http and other apps only work with https.

I am aware ssl is supported for App Engine - however, my deployment is of course on Computer Engine.

What is the best way to go with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Bitnami supports HTTPS, you just need to configure it. Consult the documentation which has detailed steps.

Answer (score 2):

Have you fiddled with the VM firewall settings? You should just need to unblock inbound traffic to the VM on port 443 to receive HTTPS traffic. This is possible on multiple screens:

1. On the "Create Instance" screen (as you're creating the VM):

[image]

2. On the instance details view after you create it:

[image]

3. On the instance's networking details view if you click through the `nic0` details on the previous screen:

[image]

If you've already enabled the firewall settings, you probably need to configure Bitnami / Mautic to use HTTPS instead of anything specific to GCE.